# Polymorphic Association ids, has_one and uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association, where an Admin and a Developer each have a User (for a common authentication mechanism)

**Developer.rb**

```
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :skype_name
  has_one :user, :as => :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**Admin.rb** is identical but doesn't add any new attributes

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_id, :profile_type
  has_secure_password

  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  ... some validations for unique email and before_save stuff ...
end
```

When I create Developers or Admins via the rails console, User.profile_id is always unique, and it is the same as the Developer or Admin I've just created. It also seems to match with the diagram [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

If I have a User with `profile_type` = `Developer`, and I want to get a reference to the Developer, is it safe to get the reference by calling `Developer.find(u.profile_id)`, and similarly for Admins? And if not, then how can I do it safely?

It works at the moment, but I'm not sure if it's just lucky because my tables are small.

Comment: Yes. The quick answer is that because you set the `profile type` to "Developer", the User `profile id` should match the one in the `Developer` table.

Comment: I'm just confused then why he defines the `find_commentable` method in this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association. (the method is viewable in the 'notes' section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The quick answer is that because you set the profile type to "Developer", the User profile id should match the one in the Developer table. Imagine for a second that you have

## User One

```
id: 1
name: Bob
profile_type: Developer
profile_id: 1
```

## User Two

```
id: 2
name: Shelly
profile_type: Admin
profile_id: 1
```

Because you set up the polymorphic association, Rails handles all the work for you. No need to worry about id conflicts. Unless of course you change User Two to

## Updated User Two

```
id: 2
name: Shelly
profile_type: Developer
profile_id: 1
```

Then Rails won't know what to do when you have two user's as the same developer.

And within your Developer and Admin's table you should find

## Developers Table

```
id: 1
skype_name Bob123
```

## Admin's Table

```
id: 1
skype_name Shelly78
```

Comment: So the unique key in the profile table is the combination of the profile_type and profile_id? Surely the User ids can't all be the same?

Comment: Yep, the profile_type tells Rails to look either in the Developer table or the Admin table for the user's association. You can also use the profile_type to set some sortof if/else statement to specify actions for developers or admins, etc. etc. Can you clarify your latter question.

Comment: in your example, your first listed attribute is "id: 1", but they're all 1. That's the key for the User table isn't it? Surely that needs to be unique?

Comment: My apoligizes, that was a copy and paste error. I updated the answer with the appropriate info.